# Can't recognize UISwipeGesture on my ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, uigesturerecognizer

In my app, there is a scrollView(pageScrollView) which is a snapchat like interface (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_daE3IL_1s)

However, when I try to use below code to get the gesture on the scroll view, it cannot detect, can anyone help me on this??

```
let leftSwipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(leftSwipedByUser(_:)))
leftSwipeGesture.direction = .left
self.pageScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipeGesture)


let rightSwipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rightSwipedByUser(_:)))
rightSwipeGesture.direction = .right
self.pageScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipeGesture)
```

And the action is below:

```
@objc func leftSwipedByUser(_ gesture:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    print("left swipe")
}
@objc func rightSwipedByUser(_ gesture:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    print("right swipe")
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3648967/5588508).

Comment: You can find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841045/how-to-have-a-uiscrollview-scroll-and-have-a-gesture-recognizer